# rtl60.bpl was not found in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi

I was using Delphi 6. Now I am upgrade the delphi 6 to delphi 10.2.3.

I uninstalled the delphi 6. I found borland folder under the program file (86) still exists. I renamed the folder . Also I removed the relative search path in the Path environment variable.

I installed the delphi 10.2.3, and fixed codes that are not compatible with the new delphi.

Building and compiling the program are all good, but running the program produce an error: "The code execution cannot proceed because rtl60.bpl was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem".

I checked the program project options, in the Package, I did not find rtl60 there.

How to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You are building using runtime packages and linking to rtl60. Which is the Delphi 6 version of the rtl package.

Comment: Somewhere in your project file, there is a link to rtl60.bpl. Just don't link to runtime packages and re-build. Clean the project (option in the project menu).

Comment: I have checked all .pas files, there is no rtl, rtl60 in the uses clause. I clean the project as well. But the error is still there. Any other way to check the link to rtl60?

Comment: Delete the project's .dropj file (and its .dof file if one still exists) and open it in the IDE. Fix all search path etc. issues and then try again. There is most likely a problem with the upgrade wizard.